# Is there a word for 'governed/demanded by laws'?

Tags: legal-terms

I'm looking for a word meaning 'governed/demanded by law' – I've thought about *legislative* as well as *lawful*, but whereas both are to do with laws, neither seems to mean '**governed/demanded by** laws'. For instance, *legislative intervention* seems to mean 'intervention by making laws', and *lawful intervention* seems to mean 'intervention allowed by law', rather than 'intervention governed/demanded by law'. Am I right about this, and, if so, what word can I use instead of *legislative* and *lawful*?

Examples (X=the word I'm looking for):

> If he is prevented from seeing his child due to X intervention by the social services, he may...

> They were unable to go through with the project due to X injunction by the local authorities

Comment: It would help if you added context, such as an example sentence or paragraph in which you would want to use such a word, so we can better understand just what words, if any, would suit.

Comment: UK legislation often uses the phrase "required by law"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Legislative** comes from Latin and means **making laws**, it is the arm of the government that proposes, discusses, and then decides what should be law. It is joined by the *Executive* (the arm that executes, again, from Latin) and the *Judicative* (the arm that judges, again, from Latin). It does *not* mean 'following the law' in any way. *Legislative intervention* means "intervention of the lawmaking body (my making new laws)".

---

**Lawful** is, according to [Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lawful):

> lawful
> 1
> . a: being in harmony with the law
> . b: constituted, authorized, or established by law : RIGHTFUL
> 2: LAW-ABIDING

This indeed is actually synonym to "following the law" or "as prescribed by the law". *Lawful intervention* means "an intervention that follows the law" and **is** what you look for.

Good synonyms for "lawful" in the use of *intervention following the law* would be [*legal*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legal) (esp. 3: conforming to or permitted by law or established rules) and [*licit*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/licit) (conforming to the requirements of the law)

However, there is no *single* word that makes a *required by law* intervention. In a legal text (here: legal in use *1: of or relating to law*) such a demand would be phrased as *mandatory intervention* or *legal obligation*. *Mandatory* means that there was no discretion of the intervening body and would fit for actions of an executive body (e.g. social services), while the second example of *injunction* does not need an extra word: *injunction* itself is a legal term meaning *a court order to do/not do something*.

Comment: Thank you! I think *mandatory* is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Helen it does *not* say anything about the legality though, just that it has to be done. mandatory is "because it is demanded" - made that a little clearer with your examples.

Comment: Right – I see the difference :) Thanks for the clarification – in your answer as well as your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to provide examples than to analyze this question in the abstract, because correct usage is quite context specific. Here are words that would fit the examples provided:

"If he is prevented from seeing his child due to **a legally authorized/court authorized/legally required** intervention by the social services, he may..."

"They were unable to go through with the project due to **a court ordered/legally authorized/legally valid** injunction by the local authorities"